# How to wotk with lists, search for duplicates in list and then output it all

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list, tab delimited:

```
Reason  Group   Customer    Node    Node Alias  Sum Count   Last time   First time  Ticket  Status  User    Type    priority
del 2   Ha5 hu45    0456b_t5    18  3   18.03.2021 22:37    18.01.2021 21:37    DN65734 4   TR  6   4
pac 5   GH6 li3 5687b_t5    5   1   18.03.2021 22:37    18.02.2021 21:37    DN65735 3   JH  3   3
wa  7   Ha5 kle 0698b_t5    6   2   18.03.2021 22:37    18.03.2021 21:37    DN65736 2   KS  9   4
del 2   FF3 dar6    0889b_t5    14  2   18.03.2021 22:37    18.04.2021 21:37    DN65737 4   TR  5   4
sus 8   Ha5 hu45    0456a_t5    3   8   18.03.2021 22:37    18.05.2021 21:37    DN65738 9   TR  6   4
```

From this list I only need three items. The code works so far (might not be optimal, but it works):

```
from tkinter import Tk                                
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()                                       
a = root.clipboard_get()                              
i = 0                                                 
j = 0                                                 
d = []                                                
e = ""                                                

# -- end of blank definitions -- let`s fiddle

while j < 10:
    a = a.replace("  "," ")                           
    j = j + 1
a = list(a.split("\n"))                               
b = len(a)
print ("total rows = ",(b))
while i <= b-1:
            c=a[i]                                    
            c=list(c.split('\t'))                     
            print ((c[4])," -- ",(c[8])," -- ",(c[9]))
            e = (c[4]),(c[8]),(c[9]),("-----")        
            d.append (e)                              
            i=i+1
print (d)
```

Now I have a problem understanding how to proceed.
I need to check the "Node Alias" if there are an "a" and "b" example - `0456b_t5 & 0456a_t5`
The a and/or b is always in the 5th position and the number in front must match. If two b's or two a's are present, ignore, but if both a & b are present I would like to add a warning" to that line / list.

My thinking was to work on the initial loop, add the output to a new list (d) and now split d up again, but how do I search a list for duplicates with the complexity of the a & b?

UPDATE:

So I decided to split my problem into smaller chunks and concentrating only on the Node and ignoring the a & b after the 4 numbers for now

```
    while i <= clipb_len-1:
                c=clipb[i]
                c=list(c.split('_'))
                print (c[1])
                e = (c[1])
                last_chars = e[4:5]
                first_chars = e[0:4]
                print('First 4 character : ', first_chars, 'Last character : ', last_chars, "\n")
                SD.append (first_chars)
                i=i+1
    SD_len = len(SD)
for value in SD:
    print(value)
dupes = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(SD).items() if count > 1]
dupes_len = len(dupes)
def Filter(clipb, dupes):
    return [str for str in clipb if
             any(sub in str for sub in dupes)]
print(Filter(clipb, dupes))
```

This gives me the duplicates I need. Having issues figuring out how to get the Index of these though.

Comment: This isn't a python `list`. It's a tab-delimited table or dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
sortedData = sorted(set(d),key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I just can`t get it working. Trying a different route